# How does a c-compiler recognizes system-calls?

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-construction

Let's say we want to create a socket using the "socket"-function.
How does the compiler know that it has to invoke a system call for that corresponding function?
Is there any internal table that records with functions belong to a specific set of library?

Comment: Either the compiler knows no such thing and simply compiles a call to this function in the standard C library, which consists of machine language code that executes this system call; or the compiler just knows that `socket()` is a system call and how to make it. The compiler just knows. It's very smart, like that.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't. Syscalls are typically made through wrapper function provided by your standard c library. The compiler then just calls `ssize_t write(int,void const*,size_t);` or any other sycall wrapper like it would call any other function, regardless of whether the instructions in it make a syscall or not.

Comment: Yes, this was my initial guess, for in c# for example, you use the keyword "extern" that has an "dllimport"-attribute. Thanks.

Comment: @ChezBorz `dllimport` is a Windows, which isn't really needed. UNIX toolchains and even some on Windows do without it. A call to a declared function just leaves a marked hole in the assembly, which the linker plugs up, either with a static libary (/an object file) or by linking with a dll/dso. Again, the mechanism is the same regardless of what's inside the linked function.

Comment: Some quick-and-helpful reading: [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Answer (score 11):

The usual method is this:

Your platform's library includes a function called `socket` that contains the actual code needed to make a system call on your platform. The compiler reads in a header file that tells it that this function exists, the linker connects the compiled code to that function, and the library's implementation of that function makes the actual system call.